# How to know which is value for field extension

Tags: field-theory

I can convert $\sqrt{5}$ into a `AlgebraicNumber`:

```
ToNumberField[Sqrt[5]]
```

> `AlgebraicNumber[Sqrt[5], {0, 1}]`

Then I extend it with another *unknown value* to get the extension result :`AlgebraicNumber[Root[576-960 #1^2+352 #1^4-40 #1^6+#1^8&,8,0],{0,-(53/12),0,95/36,0,-(97/288),0,5/576}]`. How to get the unknown value with the extension result in *MMA*?

---

Actually the *unknown value* is $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, because:

```
First[ToNumberField[{Sqrt[5], Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]}, All]]
```

> `AlgebraicNumber[Root[576-960 #1^2+352 #1^4-40 #1^6+#1^8&,8,0],{0,-(53/12),0,95/36,0,-(97/288),0,5/576}]`

But I hope to use *MMA* to get it.

Comment: Are you saying that given the complicated `Y = AlgebraicNumber[...]` form, you want to work out the X to put into `ToNumberField[{Sqrt[5], X}, All]` that would give you `Y`?

Comment: `FullSimplify[X[[1]] - X]` seems to get it where X is your algebraic number, but I'm not sure why. It also won't work well on situations where you have three surds or more in the second number. I answered, but wasn't confident on the mathematics of why... so just leaving this as a comment.

Comment: @flinty [It is exactly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277975/how-to-know-which-is-value-for-field-extension#comment694120_277975) what I'm after. May I ask if I did not express myself clearly enough in the post?

Comment: it's a clear question - I'm just not an expert on the subject area so I had to do a quick crash course on polynomial algebra and field extensions to understand what was needed. I'd love to know _why_ my `FullSimplify[X[[1]] - X]` works - I stumbled upon it entirely by accident.

Comment: @flinty I am also not an expert but I noticed that too and maybe it's related to the fact that trial and error with linear combinations can work if I understood this section : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Constructive_results

Answer (score 3):

Can be done like so. Set up the defining polynomial for the number field and one for the element in question.

```
poly = (576 - 960 #1^2 + 352 #1^4 - 40 #1^6 + #1^8 &)[x];
poly2 = z - {0, 65/12, 0, -95/36, 0, 97/288, 0, -5/576} . 
    x^Range[0, Exponent[poly, x] - 1];
```

The resultant, to remove the defining polynomial root, gives a polynomial satisfied by the algebraic element in question.

```
pz = Resultant[poly, poly2, x]

(* Out[230]= (12116574790945106558976 - 242331495818902131179520 z^2 + 
   1235890628676400869015552 z^4 - 242331495818902131179520 z^6 + 
   12116574790945106558976 z^8)/12116574790945106558976 *)
```

Now find the roots, figure out which is the one we want, and simplify it.

```
solns = Solve[pz == 0, z];
rt = Root[576 - 960 #1^2 + 352 #1^4 - 40 #1^6 + #1^8 &, 8, 0];
zsol = z /. 
  SelectFirst[solns, RootReduce[poly2 /. x -> rt /. #] == 0 &]

(* Out[233]= Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]

In[234]:= ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"][zsol]

Out[234]= Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] *)
```

The method proposed by @flinty will often work too, and is much less to type.

Comment: The coefficients in poly2 are the coefficients for `Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3]` in the number field. That is what OP is looking for so I am not sure I understood how one can find poly2

Comment: It seems like poly3 was not defined

Comment: @userrandrand That `poly3` was a holdover from an earlier version. It should have been (and now is) `poly2`. As for its coefficients, my understanding is that we are given that information via the `AlgebraicNumber[...]` input, and asked to find the simpler form `sqrt(2)+sqrt(3)`. See clarification comments under the post.

Comment: Hi, I understood the question as `ToNumberField[{Sqrt[5], X},All][[1]]=Y=Sqrt[5]+Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[2]` find X given Y and `Sqrt[5]`. I am not sure if X is unique if there is some canonicalization of Y in the algorithm. Perhaps for any rational r X*r is also a solution.

Comment: Hi, I actually already know [the field extension relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OsIH.png) for $x^5 + 250 x^2 + 625$, but that $\sqrt{-(5+2\sqrt{5})}$ took me a lot of work to figure out. Can you calculate it with your method by the 5 roots of the equation and the 10th order extension above? Those $r_i$ are the solutions to the equation

Comment: @yode I'm not sure what you are asking. Maybe add a full example to the original post?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Related [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278153/how-to-calculate-intermediate-fields-of-galois-group-in-hasse-diagram)